# C# generics error - The type string must be non nullable

Tags: c#, generics

I have generic structure for my rest API that is built on .net core 3.0

Here is my code for generic entities.

```
public interface IFullAuditedEntity
{
    object Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class FullAuditedEntity<T> : IFullAuditedEntity where T : struct
{
    public IFullAuditedEntity() { }

    [Key]
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }

    object Entity.Id
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set
        {
            Id = (T)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this structure works fine for me if my entity has **int primary key**.

But If I have to use **string as a primary key**, it gives me generics error. see below entity.

```
[Table(name: "Status")]
public class Status : FullAuditedEntity<string>
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(03)]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(03)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

See added snap for more information.

[image]

I tried to pass Nullable as some of other SO answers suggested but it didn't work for me, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `FullAuditedEntity`? Assuming it derives from `Entity<T>`, that's not going to work as `string` isn't a value type at all, nullable or non-nullable.

Comment: So, this FullAuditedEntity is Entity in given example..

Comment: "So, this FullAuditedEntity is Entity in given example.." I don't know what you mean by that. Please make sure you provide all the relevant code in your post.

Comment: `string` is for all intents and purposes immutable, but it is still a reference type.

Comment: Jon, I have updated my question.

Comment: Right. So it's just that `FullAuditedEntity` requires the type argument to be a non-nullable value type, whereas `string` is a reference type. There's not much more we can say about that - you need to work out *why* the constraint is there to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a constraint:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity where T : struct
```

so `string` is not type of `struct`, `string` is a reference type. [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

[As msdn says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> Constraints inform the compiler about the capabilities a type argument
>   must have. Without any constraints, the type argument could be any
>   type. The compiler can only assume the members of System.Object, which
>   is the ultimate base class for any .NET type. For more information,
>   see [Why use constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#why-use-constraints).

You can remove this constraint to avoid this error and now your `Id` can be any type:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity
```

As an alternative to `string` type of key and if it is eligible for your case, you can create `T` type of `Guid`. If it can be type of `Guid`, then you can avoid deletion of constraint:

```
public abstract class FullAuditedEntity<T> : IFullAuditedEntity where T : struct
{
     // ... The code is omitted for the brevity
}
```

and your entity:

```
[Table(name: "Status")]
public class Status : FullAuditedEntity<string>
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    [Guid]
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
```